# Postman Post returns success but parameters are null in response

Tags: spring-boot

This is my Product class

```java
@Entity
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    private int Product_id;
    
    private String Product_name;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

This is my service class

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class PService implements PServiceI {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository prep;

    @Override
    public Product addProduct(Product p) {
        return prep.save(p);
    }
}
```

This is my repository

```java
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer>{}
```

My request body in postman

```json
{
    "Product_id":3,
    "Product_name":"computer"
}
```

Response in postman

```json
{
    "Product_id":0,
    "Product_name":null
}
```

My Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dealer")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private PServiceI ser;
    
    @PostMapping("/addProduct")
    public Product addProduct(@RequestBody Product p){
        return ser.addProduct(p);
    }
}
```

I'm not getting what is wrong and why i'm getting null in the response

Comment: can you upload your controller

Comment: uploaded @VinayakMittal

Comment: Does data getting stored in the database?

Comment: yes, it is storing product_id as 0 and product_name as null@VinayakMittal

Comment: Hi, i got it. I just changed them to lowercase in request.@VinayakMittal

Comment: where can you specific please? @shreya

Comment: In postman post request i changed "Product_id" to "product_id" and same with product name.@VinayakMittal

Comment: ok got it @shreya